# Счетчик, как на баше

Tags: javascript

Как можно написать счетчик, как у цитат на bash.org? Вот этот, который:
+ 1243 -

Comment: фрилансером или руками с помошью гугля.

Answer (score 1):

Делается при помощи PHP.
При нажатии на кнопку к базе отправляется запрос, в котором оценка инкрементируется.

Comment: От JS там только Аякс.